# How to highlight a checked radio button using jquery validate highlight property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-validate

I am trying to add some new functionality to something that was previously written by some other guy, I need to highlight a radio button after a validation on one of grid element which is in the same row as the radio butotn.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
     "CountyCheck",
     function (value, element) {             
             if ($("input[type='radio']:checked").closest('tr').find('select') && $("input[type='radio']:checked").closest('tr').find('select').length > 0) {
                 if ($("input[type='radio']:checked").closest('tr').find('select').val() != '')
                     return ($.trim($('#tobevalidated').val()).toLowerCase() === $.trim($("input[type='radio']:checked").closest('tr').find('select').val()).toLowerCase());
                 else
                     return true;
             }
             else {
                 return ($.trim($('#tobevalidated').val()).toLowerCase() === $.trim($("input[type='radio']:checked").closest('tr').find('.labelclass').html()).toLowerCase());
             }          
     }, "");
```

the above validation method checks for the radio buttons in a grid and searches for the drop down list(if one exists) or a label and checks if the selected option/label value is equal to a certain value to be validated.(#tobevalidated). The cshtml for the grid looks some thing like this:

```
var grid = addresses != null ? new WebGrid(addresses, canSort: false, canPage: false) : new WebGrid(new List<Address>(), canSort: false, canPage: false);
var gridColumns = new List<WebGridColumn>();

gridColumns.Add(grid.Column("", format: item => Html.RadioButton("IsStandardized", true, ((bool?)item.IsStandardized).GetValueOrDefault(), new { data_SerializedAddressData = (string)item.JSonSerializedAddressData }), style: "webgridcol1Width"));
gridColumns.Add(grid.Column("Address1", "Address1", style: "addrLine"));
gridColumns.Add(grid.Column("Address2", "Address2", style: "addrLine"));
gridColumns.Add(grid.Column("City", "City", style: "webgridcol2Width"));
gridColumns.Add(grid.Column("State", "State", style: "webgridcol2Width"));
gridColumns.Add(grid.Column(header: "Postal Code", style: "webgridcol2Width", format: item => CommonUtility.GetZipCode((Address)item.Value, true)));
gridColumns.Add(grid.Column("Country", "Country", style: "webgridcol2Width"));
//TODO: Need to see how to add AddressType to Standardized Addresses or just check with updated Address' AddressType
if (updatedAddresses.Any(addr => !(addr.AddressType == AddressCodeEnum.BillingAddress || addr.AddressType == AddressCodeEnum.MailingAddress)))
{
    gridColumns.Add(grid.Column(columnName: "County", header: "County", style: "countyname", format: addr =>
       {
           if (addr.StandardizedCounties != null && addr.StandardizedCounties.Count > 1)
           {
               bool isRadioSelected = ((bool?)addr.IsStandardized).GetValueOrDefault();
               List<SelectListItem> countiesList = Html.ConvertToSelectList<string>((List<string>)addr.StandardizedCounties, (a) => a, (a) => a, true, isRadioSelected ? Model.StandardizedAddress.County : "");
               MvcHtmlString returnValue = Html.DropDownList((string)string.Format("CountyDDL[{0}]", addr.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(addr)), countiesList);
               return returnValue;
           }
           else
           {
               String county = (addr.StandardizedCounties != null && addr.StandardizedCounties.Count == 1) ? Model.County : addr.County;
               return county;
           }
       }));
}
```

I want to highlight the checked radio button when the validation fails, but the problem is jquery-validate.js

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if (element.type === 'radio') {
            this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        }
    }
```

uses something like this to add a css class, since the element.name in this is same for all the radio buttons, but I want to just highlight the button which is checked.

I used something like this in the highlight method of the validate.js

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if (element.type === 'radio') {
            $(element).is(":checked").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        }
    },
```

but this does not seem to work and more over it reloads the page whenever the validation is fired.

I am really nub at this and if any one could point me in the right direction, that would be of great help.
Thanks!

Comment: There is **absolutely nothing** in the `highlight` function that is reloading your page... that's coming from someplace else.

Comment: Exactly! but the reload happened after I Changed the highlight function though.

Comment: That's why it's called coincidence.   The jQuery `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` methods do not have the power to reload a page.  However, if you somehow broke your validation, then the page might reload as a result of a form submit.  You'll have to look at your JavaScript console and do some basic troubleshooting.

Comment: I'll have to do that, besides the above approach I also tried adding the 'errorClass' to the entire element, which resulted in adding the highlight class to all the radio button, so I figured $(element).is(":checked") should select the radio button which is checked, but as you can see, that did not go the way I expected.

Comment: Look inside the source code of the plugin for clues about the radio button issue.  The default version of `highlight` already has a conditional that properly selects the `radio` and `checkbox` types.  You can use that part of the code within your custom `highlight` function.  Otherwise, it looks like you just want the default... and in that case, ***remove*** your custom `highlight` function entirely and see how it works.